# Side affects installing node modules and changing Node.js version?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, nvm

Are there any issues or side affects to installing node modules under a particular Node.js version, changing the version of Node.js (eg. with NVM or a general node upgrade), and using the previously installed node modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there are! If I install a module tested against a certain version of node and thereafter I update my node version, I can’t guarantee that the module will still work as expected.

There is an optional field `engines` that can be set in the package.json; from here, the module publisher can specify the version of node needed for his module to work, e.g.

`{ "engines" : { "node" : ">=4 <6" } }`

This will send a warning message during the package installation if your node version is not supported.

Comment: Why do you need to reinstall global NPM packages?

Comment: NVM aside (as it's not core to Node.js), is there any evidence to suggest incompatibilities of node modules between Node.js versions? AFAIK the internal contents of a node modules remains the same, and I doubt the NPM 3 flat folder structure introduces any incompatibilities.

Comment: Perfect, that's the answer I was looking for... if you edit your answer to include that reasoning I will accept it... also if there's anything else you could think of too please include that also :)